# Security Exception running dotless

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, dotless

I'm getting a Security Exception when I attempt to access a .less file in IIS7.

The exception text is:

> **Security Exception**
>
> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
> security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
> please contact your system administrator or change the application's
> trust level in the configuration file.

I've added the following to my web.config file:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler,dotless.Core" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
  <add type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" path="*.LESS" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<dotless minifyCss="false" cache="false" />  

<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="dotLess" path="*.less" verb="*" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Any ideas?

I'm running a MVC2 .Net application.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the MIME type to IIS?
if no add extension .less  MIME type 'text/css'

Comment: Hi, I hadn't added it.  However, I just did and it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Could it be that your IIS Process doesn't have permission to access the less file?
Never heard of this problem before..